# Mongoose/Express : average of subdocuments

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have the following models :

Product :

```
var ProductSchema = new Schema({
name: String,
comments: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment'}],
_user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}
});
```

Comment :

```
var CommentSchema = new Schema({
text: String,
rating: Number,
_product: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product'}
});
```

What I do currently is retrieve all Products along with their user :

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
Product.find().populate('_user').exec(function (err, products) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(products);
});
});
```

I'd like to add to the results an "average" field that contains the average of all comments for each product so the results would look like this :

```
[{name: "Product 1", _user: {name: "Bob"}, average: 7.65},...]
```

Is this possible with a unique query ? Do I need to compute and store the average in the Product document each time a new Comment is added ?

Thanks !

Comment: Have a look at the Mongoose Virtual Fields: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should try with calculating the "Running Average".
You only need to know how many ratings there are, and what is their average. Having same average value saved for every document in MongoDB should be bad practice, I hope this will help you.
So you could create schema like this:

```
var AverageProductRatingSchema = new Schema({
  productId:       {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product'},
  averageRating:   {type: Number},
  numberOfRatings: {type: Number}
});
```

Then just implement addRating() function something like this:

```
function addRating(newRating, productId) {
  /* Find document that holds average rating of wanted product */
  AverageProductRating.findOneAsync({productId: productId})
    .then(function (avgProdRating) {

       /* 
         Calculate new average using the Running Average method.
         http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1627-create-a-running-average-without-storing-individual-values.htm
       */
       var newAverageRating = (avgProdRating.averageRating * avgProdRating.numberOfRatings + newRating) / (avgProdRating.numberOfRatings + 1);
       var newNumberOfRatings = avgProdRating.numberOfRatings + 1;

       AverageProductRating.update(
         { productId: productId },
         {
           $set: {
             averageRating:   newAverageRating,
             numberOfRatings: newNumberOfRatings 
         }
       });
     });

}
```

This is the link that describes similiar issue:
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1627-create-a-running-average-without-storing-individual-values.htm

Comment: Why do you say that the same average value is saved for every document ?
Each product has the average of all its reviews.
The average is stored inside the Product document, and only recomputed when a new reviews is added, changed, or removed.

Comment: Maybe we have a bit of misunderstanding. I wanted to help you so you don't have to go through all comments calculating new rating. You only add rating from new comment and do simple calculation. Now imagine you have thousands of comments with ratings on some product. Every time you need average rating, you would have to query DB for all comments and calculate average. This "running average" algorithm should prevent that. Ofcourse, you can keep average rating stored within Product document collection that you already have.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean now, that makes sense. Thanks !